# Get Nearby Bluetooth devices in react native

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-ble-plx

I'm looking for to get nearby bluetooth devices in react-native. I have used some react-native libraries but while scanning with serviceUUID sometimes iOS devices are not able to detect in android and vice-versa. Even-though I advertise/broadcasting in iOS & Android but still not able to detect in iOS & Android.

Is there any library in react-native to detect all the devices in iOS & Android?.

Comment: have you find any libraries